# Isomorphism between $D_{2n}/Z(D_{2n})$ and $D_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

I need some help with the following task:

Show that  for all $n\geq2$ is $D_{2n}/Z(D_{2n})\cong D_n$

$D_n$ is the dihedrial group with $2n$ elements and looks like $D_n=\{id,r,...,r^{n-1},s,sr,...,sr^{n-1}\}$

Sadly I have no idea how $D_{2n}/Z(D_n)$  looks like but I guess I need to know that to show that it is a homomorphism and bijectiv.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Is that $Z(D_n)$ (the center of $D_n$) or $\Bbb Z(D_n)$ (which I don't know how to interpret)?

Comment: oh, im sorry. Its the center of $D_n$

Comment: Also, I suspect that it should be $D_{2n}/Z(D_{\color{red}{2n}})$, is that right?

Comment: Im really sorry for that. Normally I double check my posts. Sorry.... I changed it

Comment: No need to apologize. The fact that you wrote your question clearly and explained your thoughts makes your question much better than the ones that I'm used to seeing, even if there were a few typos

Comment: The claim is proved in the duplicate: **Claim.** If $n\geq 3$ and $n$ is even, then $D_{2n}/Z(D_{2n})\cong D_n$. For $n\ge 3$ odd, $D_{2n}$ has trivial center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** By the first isomorphism theorem, it is equivalent to find a homomorphism $f:D_{2n} \to D_n$ with $\ker(f) = Z(D_{2n})$.

Let $s_n,r_n$ denote the generators of $D_{n}$ and let $s_{2n},r_{2n}$ denote the generators of $D_{2n}$. Define the map $f:D_{2n} \to D_n$ by
$$
f(s_{2n}^j r_{2n}^k) = s_{n}^jr_n^k.
$$
Verify that $f$ is a homomorphism and that $\ker(f) = Z(D_{2n})$. In verifying that $f$ is a homomorphism, you might find the identity
$
sr^ks = r^{-k}
$
to be useful.

Comment: Do you mean $f(s_{2n}^j r_{2n}^k) = f(s_{n}^jr_n^k)$ or just $f(s_{2n}^j r_{2n}^k) = s_{n}^jr_n^k$  ?

Comment: @Why The latter; thanks for pointing that out